# Parsing XML with REXML

Tags: ruby, xml

I have this XML document and I want to find an specific GitHubCommiter using REXML. Hoy do I do that?

```
<users>
 <GitHubCommiter id="Nerian">
  <username>name</username>
  <password>12345</password>
 </GitHubCommiter>

 <GitHubCommiter id="xmawet">
  <username>name</username>
  <password>12345</password>
 </GitHubCommiter>

 <GitHubCommiter id="JulienChristophe">
  <username>name</username>
  <password>12345</password>
  </GitHubCommiter>
</users>
```

I have tried:

```
log = REXML::Document.new(file)                                                      
root = log.root                                                                         username = root.elements["GitHubCommiter['#{github_user_name}']"].elements['username'].text      
password =     root.elements["GitHubCommiter['#{github_user_name}']"].elements['password'].text
root.elements["GitHubCommiter['id'=>'#{github_user_name}']"].text
```

But I don't find a way to do it. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs say for `elements`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/rexml/rdoc/classes/REXML/Elements.html) (emphasis mine):

> `[]( index, name=nil)`
> Fetches a child element. Filters only Element children, regardless of the XPath match.
>
> `index:` the search parameter. This is either an Integer, which will be used to find the index‘th child Element, **or an XPath, which will be used to search for the Element.**

So it needs to be XPath:

```
root.elements["./GitHubCommiter[@id = '{github_user_name}']"]
```

etc.